# Embedded Eventbrite checkout widget prevents page scroll upon close

Tags: widget, eventbrite, webflow

I am creating an event page on our site and integrating the Eventbrite checkout modal to keep the ticket buying experience on our website. The whole thing appears to work well until the user exits the modal. After the modal goes away, the website page doesn’t respond to scrolling. Any ideas?

Here’s the published site so you can see the embedded code. Click any of the “Get Your Ticket” buttons to trigger the Eventbrite checkout modal. After it loads, try exiting by clicking the “X” in the top right:
https://the-startup-story.webflow.io/events/startup-story-live-dallas

Here’s my preview link so you can see the code:
https://preview.webflow.com/preview/the-startup-story?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=the-startup-story&preview=1a5291aabf7762f0ee1084e522fdec25&pageId=5df01420ac038e5da652cd38&mode=preview

I contacted Eventbrite support and we tried using the default code (without any of my button customizations) and that didn’t fix the issue unfortunately.

Here’s an example of this Eventbrite embedded checkout working fine elsewhere:
https://www.thenewparish.com/

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that I had several buttons that link to the checkout widget and apparently you can only have one. I removed all but one buttons that pulled up the widget and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The embed code looks like

```
<button id="eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-136611252222" type="button">Buy Tickets</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var exampleCallback = function() {
        console.log('Order complete!');
    };

    window.EBWidgets.createWidget({
        widgetType: 'checkout',
        eventId: '136611252222',
        modal: true,
        modalTriggerElementId: 'eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-136611252222',
        onOrderComplete: exampleCallback
    });
</script>
```

You can have more than one on each page but you need to adjust somethings to avoid errors that break the scroll.

The main issue is leaving exampleCallback as exampleCallback  as you will try and trigger a function that is defined in multiple places

Either rename the exampleCallback in each button or remove the duplicated functions

Additionally, you should change the ids of the buttons and modalTriggerElementId: to be unique